# How to exit clink's Vi editing mode

Tags: cmd.exe, clink

I'm using Vi editing mode in clink. I can't see any other way of exiting Vi mode than closing the shell with Ctrl-D and restart. Clink's keyboard help lists two keyboard shortcuts for entering Vi mode (A-C-j and A-C-m) but none for exiting. I read somewhere that C-e switches back "to emacs mode" but that doesn't work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it. It turns out there are two sets of keyboard shortcuts in Vi mode:

- one for insert mode (which is the default): press Alt-h to see the shortcuts
- another one for Vi command mode: press Esc to go into command mode, then Alt-h to see the shortcuts

So in Vi command mode Ctrl-e indeed works - switches back to "emacs mode".